# When I login, it redirects me to profile page rather I want to stay on same page. Any solution?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect

Currently, I'm using this code that is also copied from one thread of StackOverflow but it's not working.

```
if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') 
    || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) 
{

    add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
    function my_login_redirect() {
        $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        wp_safe_redirect($location);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to borrow other peoples code thats fine! But you do have to read and FULLY Understand what it is doing before you Implement it in your code

Comment: actually I'm not a developer. So taking help from experts is fine.. my thoughts..

Comment: I said it was fine! But if you dont understand what the code does, then maybe its doing something REALLY NASTY.

Comment: Found this that might help you : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66974/login-redirect-to-previous-page

Comment: already tried that, It's about login errors. if you go in bottom you will see the person still having redirect problem same as me.

Comment: The `my_login redirect` command will initiate a redirect. If you don't want to redirect, then don't use it.